# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs

My react app gives me this warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency  Either include it or
>   remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

If I move my Stateful components to the inside of the useEffect hook, then my Buttons can't access setButton anymore. Is there any way to fix this issue?

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [buttonValue, setButton] = useState(false)
```

This is my useEffect Hook

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/').then(res => setValue(res.data))

    if (buttonValue === 'delete') {
      setLoading(true)
      axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/delete').then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        setButton(null)
      })
    } else if (buttonValue === 'create') {
      setLoading(true)
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/').then(() => {
        setLoading(false)
        setButton(null)
      })
    }
  }, [isLoading])
```

These are my Buttons

```
   <Form>
     <Form.Group>
       <Button variant='success' className='button' onClick={() => setButton('create')} id='create'>Create Sales Order</Button>
     </Form.Group>
     <Form.Group>
       <Button variant='danger' className='button' onClick={() => setButton('delete')} id='delete'>Delete Sales Order</Button>
     </Form.Group>
   </Form>
```

Comment: It just wants you to add `buttonValue` to the dependency array. With the current setup the effect will only run on mount, and when `isLoading` changes. But since you're using `buttonValue` within the hook, it is warning you that you should include it as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

useEffect will re-run the effect callback whenever any of the items in dependency array changes (e.g. loading goes from false to true).

The warning you are receiving is because you have used **buttonValue** in your effect callback but not included in the dependency array. So when you call the **setButton()** in click handler of the button, nothing happens because the useEffect won't detect any change to re-run the effect callback.

However, I suggest that you change the implementation, useEffect should be used for **Side Effects** (e.g. triggering a list update when the user selects a dropdown), not the effect themselves (Clicking on a submit buttons).

I would rewrite the code like this:

```js
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/').then(res => setValue(res.data))
  }, [])


  const handleCreateClick = () => {
      setLoading(true);
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/create').then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

  const handleDeleteClick = () => {
      setLoading(true);
      axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/delete').then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }


  return (
        <Form>
          <Form.Group>
             <Button variant='success' className='button' onClick={handleCreateClick} id='create'>Create Sales Order</Button>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
             <Button variant='danger' className='button' onClick={handleDeleteClick} id='delete'>Delete Sales Order</Button>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
  );
```

The approach above is more readable and less error-prone as we are separating the effects from side-effects.